# Why does a vertical arrow get rendered incorrectly?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing a table with arrows in it. All the arrows are fine except for vertical ones pointing down.  Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}


  \tikzset{ 
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={rectangle,text width=1.5em,align=center},
        text height=1.1ex,
        nodes in empty cells,
    },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (mat) [table]{
    &&0&0\\
    &0&1&2\\
    1&1&1&2\\
    1&2&2&2\\
    1&3&3&3\\
};

\begin{scope}[shorten >=7pt,shorten <= 7pt]

\draw[->]  (mat-1-3.center) -- (mat-2-4.center);
\draw[->]  (mat-2-4.center) -- (mat-3-4.center);

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The arrow pointing down is rendered in a very strange way.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You shorten your arrow by 14 pt (`[shorten >=7pt,shorten <= 7pt]`)  but your vertical arrow is shorter than this length.

Comment: I changed the `text height=1.1ex` to `text height=1.5ex` and `4pt` instead of `7pt` in `shorten` option. It seems good.

Comment: With `        row sep=5pt,
        column sep=5pt,` and `\begin{scope}

\draw[->,shorten >=-7pt,shorten <= -7pt]  (mat-1-3.south east) -- (mat-2-4.north west);
\draw[->]  (mat-2-4.south) -- (mat-3-4.north);

\end{scope}` you can achieve the following output:    https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Mzl.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you increase the space between rows?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{ 
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=3ex,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={rectangle,text width=1.5em,align=center},
        text height=1.1ex,
        nodes in empty cells,
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=7pt,shorten <= 7pt]
    \matrix (mat) [table]{
    &&0&0\\
    &0&1&2\\
    1&1&1&2\\
    1&2&2&2\\
    1&3&3&3\\
};
\draw[->]  (mat-1-3.center) -- (mat-2-4.center);
\draw[->]  (mat-2-4.center) -- (mat-3-4.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also use `tikz-cd` and simplify your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    &&0\ar[dr]&0\\
    &0&1&2\ar[d]\\
    1&1&1&2\\
    1&2&2&2\\
    1&3&3&3\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:* it's very difficult to have a table with 27 rows and columns and also arrows.

I tried with `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\noindent Some blind text just to show that the table is larger than text width. Blah blah

\begin{adjustbox}{width=.9\paperwidth, center}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=8pt,
row sep=12pt]
    1\ar[dr] &  2\ar[r] &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10\ar[r] &  11  &   12  &   13  &   14\ar[dr]   &   15  &   16\ar[d]    &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
2   &   2\ar[d] &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
3   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
4   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
5   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
6   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
7   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
8   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
9   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
10  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
11  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
12  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
13  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
14  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
15  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
16  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
17  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
18  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
19  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
20  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
21  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
22  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
23  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
24  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
25  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
26  &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9   &   10  &   11  &   12  &   13  &   14  &   15  &   16  &   17  &   18  &   19  &   20  &   21  &   22  &   23  &   24  &   25  &   26  &   27  \\
27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  &   27  \\
\end{tikzcd}%
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The table will have many more rows and columns so I can’t afford to increase its overall size sadly. I didn’t know about tikz-cd, that looks great.

Comment: @Anush You can also increase only one row distance, also with `tikz-cd` you can set row distances as you like. How many rows and columns do you have?

Comment: 27 rows and columns.

Comment: @Anush And have all the cells 2 digits at the maximum? I'll update my answer asap, sorry, no time at the moment.

Comment: Yes 2 digits maximum as you say.

Comment: @Anush See my edit, indeed it's very difficult to have a so large table! If you have only few arrows, it's possible to set the distance larger only for few columns.

Comment: Thanks so much again!

Comment: I still can't get my real example to work, sadly. I am posting a follow up.

Comment: @Anush marmot answered to your new question.